# If I can only buy games as gifts on Steam and not as keys, where do 3rd party resellers get theirs?

Tags: steam

3rd party game key resellers like Kinguin or G2A sell game keys right? Supposedly the key sellers are just other users. I as a user as well cannot seem to buy keys from Steam though? I can only buy the games as a gift.

With that in mind, where do these 3rd party resellers buy their keys to begin with? I highly doubt they buy it from the developer themselves since there seems to be a bad relationship between the two groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I as a user as well cannot seem to buy keys from Steam though?

There are a number of legitimate sites which provide Steam keys with purchases, such as [Humble Bundle](https://www.humblebundle.com/), [Fanatical](https://www.fanatical.com/en/), and [Green Man Gaming](https://www.greenmangaming.com/). In addition, the developer/publisher of the game can generate keys and sell them however they'd like, or even give them out freely.  Steam provides an API for both of these cases.

Cheap keys on reseller sites are usually one (or more) of:

- Purchased during a sale
- Purchased in a country with lower prices, but still considered the same "region"
- Included in a "bundle" which contains multiple games for dirt-cheap *(Humble Bundle and Fanatical have a lot of these)*
- Given away *en masse* by developers on sites like [SteamGifts](https://www.steamgifts.com)
- Leaked from some database

Only in the last case are the keys illegally obtained (and will likely be revoked).  Unfortunately there's no way to tell a legitimate key apart from an illegitimate one on these reseller sites.

Comment: So they're essentially jsut buying from other sites like GMG or HumbleBundle as well